# Prove $\forall p, 0<p<m$ the integral $\int_{\mathbb{R}^m}\frac{d\mu(x)}{||x-y||^p}<\infty$ for almost all $y\in\mathbb{R}^m$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> $\mu $ is finite borel measure  in $\mathbb{R}^m$
> Prove $\forall p, 0<p<m$ the integral $\int_{\mathbb{R}^m}\frac{d\mu(x)}{||x-y||^p}<\infty$ for almost all $y\in\mathbb{R}^m$

I know that this question can be solved with polar coordinates but I want to prove this with Tonelli thm. if possible. Any help will be welcome :)

Comment: Hello my friend, can I ask you do you know what happen when $p\geq m$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We may assume that $\mu$ is a probability measure. Let $B(0,r)$ denote the Euclidean ball of radius $r$ around $0$ in $\mathbb{R}^m$. First observe that for $0<p<m$ and $0<R<\infty$, the Lebesgue integral $$I_R(x):=\int_{B(0,R)}\frac{dy}{||x-y||^p}$$ can be bounded by some constant $C(R,m,p)<\infty$. For $x \notin B(0,2R)$ this is clear, and for $x \in B(0,2R)$ it can be inferred via polar coordinates or dividing space into shells: For any integer  $k$, the contribution of the shell $\{y: 2^{-k}<||y-x|| \le 2^{1-k}\}$ to $I_R(x)$ is
$O(2^{k(p-m)})$, and we can sum this over $-\log_2(R)-2<k<\infty$.

Denote $J(y)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^m}\frac{d\mu(x)}{||x-y||^p}$. Then   by Tonelli,
$$\int_{B(0,R)} J(y) \, dy =\int_{\mathbb{R}^m} I_R(x) \, d\mu(x) \le C(R,m,p) \,,$$
so $J(y)<\infty $ for a.e. $y \in B(0,R)$. Take countable union over integer $R<\infty$.